# Export data when making a R package

Tags: r

I'm trying to make an R package to export my R function called function1 and uses some R data elements. So, I created a package skeleton using:

```
package.skeleton(list=c("function1",
                        "data1.data",
                        "data2.data",
                        "data3.data",
                        ), name="mypackage")
```

In the NAMESPACE file, I have the lines:

```
exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")
export(data1.data, data2.data, data3.data)
```

After building this package, I install the package using `install.packages('mypackage.tar.gz',,type='source',repos=NULL)`

The installation is successful, but when I try to run function1 I get the error:

```
Error in namespaceExport(ns, exports) : 
  undefined exports: data1.data, data2.data, data3.data
```

How do I export these data elements correctly? I thought the export(data1.data...) lines in the NAMESPACE file would do it, but apparently not. I tried reading the R manual but it seems very confusing on the NAMESPACE point and mostly about how to export python or C++ data. I just want to export a function and some data that's all in R.

Comment: never used package.skeleton, but your data needs to be in a directory called data and data sets are not exported in the namespace. does package.skeleton do that?

Comment: You'd be doing yourself a favor to use `roxygen2` and let it take care of the namespace for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Turns out that I shouldn't put export(data1...) in the NAMESPACE file.

Instead, data is loaded separately after the library(mypackage) call by calling:

```
data('data1.data');
data('data2.data');
data('data3.data');
```